# Login error when using firebase auth with flutter (firebase_auth/unknown)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am getting an unknown error a few times when I try to log into my flutter app using my wi-fi network and some users (minority) also have difficulty logging in. The error :

```
E/flutter (20396): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred.
[Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com/2800:3f0:4001:81f::200a:443]
```

But when I login using mobile network, it logs in normally, without error. Any idea how to solve this?

My login function:

```
Future<void> signIn(
      {LocalUser user, Function onFail, Function onSucess}) async {
    loading = true;
    try {
      final UserCredential authResult = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: user.email, password: user.password);

     [...code]
  
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      loading = false;
      onFail(getErrorString(e));
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request to a server, it responds with a response (in the form of JSON). Flutter casts JSON file into a class in order to be able to work with it. When you aren't connected to the internet, there is no response. So Flutter can't cast a non-existent data to a class. As a result, an error is raised. One way of solving this is using **try-catch**.

```
 try {
          // Some Code that you expect to work
        } catch (e) {
          // Handle Unexpected Error
        }
```

Comment: My problem is that using wi-fi network, sometimes the error message is not displayed and keeps charging infinitely. But when I use mobile network, everything works fine. And some users are having the same problem.

Comment: I edited above and put my login function 

Comment: Not only login with e-mail, but also all other login methods (Facebook and Google) have the same problem, it's like getting stuck in the part of getting the credential and the "catch" doesn't happen, the function gets stuck on that .